# R 3.4.0 tm.plugin.webmining installation fails

Tags: r

All -

I recently had a box at work patched (RHEL 6.8) and it updated my version of R from 3.3.3 to 3.4.0. No biggie this happens - the only complication is that I have to go back and install packages that I need under the new version. One package I rely on is the `tm.plugin.webmining` package.

One of my jobs was failing and when I ran that manually I got a bunch of garbage back about that package, so I figured it was something messed up so I attempted to reinstall it, but I keep getting errors.

I've considered rolling back a version of R, but that would require a bunch of work and I really would like to move forward with the new version. Here is the console output of my R session when trying to install the package:

```
 > install.packages("tm.plugin.webmining")
Installing package into â/root/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4â
(as âlibâ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Secure CRAN mirrors 

 1: 0-Cloud [https]                   2: Algeria [https]                
 3: Australia (Canberra) [https]      4: Australia (Melbourne 1) [https]
 5: Australia (Perth) [https]         6: Austria [https]                
 7: Belgium (Ghent) [https]           8: Brazil (RJ) [https]            
 9: Brazil (SP 1) [https]            10: Bulgaria [https]               
11: Chile 1 [https]                  12: China (Lanzhou) [https]        
13: Colombia (Cali) [https]          14: Czech Republic [https]         
15: Denmark [https]                  16: Estonia [https]                
17: France (Lyon 1) [https]          18: France (Lyon 2) [https]        
19: France (Marseille) [https]       20: France (Montpellier) [https]   
21: France (Paris 2) [https]         22: Germany (GÃ¶ttingen) [https]    
23: Germany (MÃ¼nster) [https]        24: Greece [https]                 
25: Iceland [https]                  26: Indonesia (Jakarta) [https]    
27: Ireland [https]                  28: Italy (Padua) [https]          
29: Japan (Tokyo) [https]            30: Malaysia [https]               
31: Mexico (Mexico City) [https]     32: Norway [https]                 
33: Philippines [https]              34: Serbia [https]                 
35: Spain (A CoruÃ±a) [https]         36: Spain (Madrid) [https]         
37: Sweden [https]                   38: Switzerland [https]            
39: Turkey (Denizli) [https]         40: Turkey (Mersin) [https]        
41: UK (Bristol) [https]             42: UK (Cambridge) [https]         
43: UK (London 1) [https]            44: USA (CA 1) [https]             
45: USA (IA) [https]                 46: USA (KS) [https]               
47: USA (MI 1) [https]               48: USA (OR) [https]               
49: USA (TN) [https]                 50: USA (TX 1) [https]             
51: Vietnam [https]                  52: (other mirrors)                


Selection: 50
trying URL 'https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/tm.plugin.webmining_1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 263472 bytes (257 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 257 KB

* installing *source* package âtm.plugin.webminingâ ...
** package âtm.plugin.webminingâ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading

 *** caught bus error ***
address 0x7ffcfbdcf870, cause 'non-existent physical address'

Traceback:
 1: .External(RinitJVM, boot.classpath, parameters)
 2: .jinit()
 3: .jpackage(pkgname, lib.loc = libname)
 4: fun(libname, pkgname)
 5: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 6: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 7: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 8: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
 9: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
10: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
11: asNamespace(ns)
12: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
13: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc, keep.source, partial = TRUE)
14: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
15: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package, lib.loc,     keep.source, partial = TRUE))
16: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     compress = compress)
17: makeLazyLoading(pkg_name, lib, keep.source = keep.source)
18: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
19: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
20: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
21: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
22: try({    suppressPackageStartupMessages(.getRequiredPackages(quietly = TRUE))    makeLazyLoading(pkg_name, lib, keep.source = keep.source)})
23: do_install_source(pkg_name, instdir, pkg, desc)
24: do_install(pkg)
25: tools:::.install_packages()
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
/usr/lib64/R/bin/INSTALL: line 34: 19398 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
     19399 Bus error               (core dumped) | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --slave --args ${args}

The downloaded source packages are in
        â/tmp/RtmphtZnGE/downloaded_packagesâ
Warning message:
In install.packages("tm.plugin.webmining") :
  installation of package âtm.plugin.webminingâ had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm kind of lost at this point on what my next move is... Thanks!

Charles

Comment: have you tried installing via github? `devtools::install_github("mannau/tm.plugin.webmining")`

also, mind if you share your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I had weird problems with R 3.4.0 that were solved by upgrading to 3.4.1.

Comment: @hongsy - I did attempt the github install and got the same error, but after a bunch of other stuff happened.

Comment: @mikeck - I will try and upgrade to 3.4.1 and see how that works.... I need to get in touch with my Unix admins and have them add that to our internal repo before I can do so, but I hope that fixes it. I will try and get back with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing 3.4.1, the tm.plugin.webmining package still had issues installing, so I ended up writing my own function using base package dependencies for my needs. Just want d to post an update....